# php get request returns empty

Tags: php, curl

file_get_contents returns an empty string on the url: http://thepiratebay.org/search/a

when it is obviosly not empty.
also tried curl, heres my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$cookieFile = 'cookies.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');

$url = 'http://thepiratebay.org/search/a';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$html = curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($html);
$html = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($html);

curl_close ($ch); unset($ch);
```

output is :

```
string(143) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2011 20:27:01 GMT
Server: lighttpd

"
string(0) ""
```

if i change the url to "http://thepiratebay.org/search" by deleting 2 chars everything is ok and i get a good response.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set the user-agent string using `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`.  Try using `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` and that should solve your problem.  You can do the same time using a [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) or [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) if you'd rather use `file_get_contents`.

Example for all three techniques are available at http://www.seopher.com/articles/how_to_change_your_php_user_agent_to_avoid_being_blocked_when_using_curl.

Comment: lolz, stupid mistake, ty, it was the CURLOPT_USERAGENT, i ended up writing this in python :)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` may not be able to open URLs in your install. See [fopen_wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). Or thepiratebay.org may be blocking you because of the user-agent on the `file_get_contents` call. Try passing a [context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php). Or maybe it isn't returning anything because you aren't sending any cookies in your `file_get_contents` call like you are with `curl`. Bottom line, even though the URLs are the same, the requests are different.